# Best Practice with MVC4 and EF5 to apply changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have a CustomerOrder-view where I would like to change an existing CustomerOrder.

I have a viewmodel that very simpliefied looks something like this:

```
        public class CustomerOrderViewModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<OrderRow> OrderRows { get; set; } 

    }

    public class OrderRow
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int price { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }    
    }
```

I also have a database with mapping tables / fields.

In my GET Action Method I load the Order with the help of Automapper like this:

```
  var customerOrder =  using (var ctx = new My_Entities()) {
                return ctx.CustomerOrders.
                    Include("Orderrows").
                    Include("Customer").
                    Single(o => o.CustomerOrderID == id); 
            }
  var model= AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<DataAccessLayer.CustomerOrder, CustomerOrderViewModel>(customerOrder);
```

In the View I use Knockout to bind to a viewmodel there, where the user can update the CustomerOrder. That includes editing Customer information and adding new orderrows etc.

Then in the post back a map the ViewModel back to the ObjectContext CustomerOrder:

```
var customerOrderToBeSaved =
            AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<CustomerOrderViewModel, CustomerOrder>(
                customerOrderViewModel);
        try
        {
            using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
            {

                ctx.CustomerOrders.Attach(customerOrderToBeSaved);
                ctx.CustomerOrders.ApplyCurrentValues(customerOrderToBeSaved);
                ...
                ctx.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
```

I get the error message: **An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.**

OK, that I can understand. But how should I go about this? Can I get the existing object and apply Changes to that one, because that is really what I'd like. I've tried to look up the old one and detach it but I haven't got it to wrok.Perhaps I'm doing this in a completely wrong way. Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not attach `customerOrderToBeSaved`, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466205.aspx) about the argument of `ApplyCurrentValues`.

> The *detached* object that has property updates to apply to the original object.

So you've got to load the entity from the database into the context and then `ApplyCurrentValues` with the detached object that has the new values.

Comment: OK... So from what I understand I should do somehthing like:

var foo = ctx.CustomerOrder.FirstOrDefault(co => co.ID = id);
ctx.CustomerOrder.ApplyCurrentValues(editedCustomerOrder);

var foo2 = ctx.Customer.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID = foo.CustomerID);
ctx.Customer.ApplyCurrentValues(editedCustomerOrder.Customer);

etc...

Comment: I don't understand why `FirstOrDefault` is there twice. But the essence is that `editedCustomerOrder` is not attached.

Comment: One FirstOrDefault is for CustomerOrder and the other for the attached Customer. I tried with include, but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't **have** to load the row from the database to update it.

You can do something like this:

```
var entity = ctx.CustomerOrders.Attach(customerOrderToBeSaved);
ctx.Entry( entity ).State = EntityState.Modified;
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

This will tell EF to issue an UPDATE SQL statement that overwrites **all** the columns in the record.

You can select which columns you want to update like this:

```
var entity = ctx.CustomerOrders.Attach(customerOrderToBeSaved);

var entry = ctx.Entry( entity );
entry.Property( o => o.<ColumnPropertyToUpdate> ).IsModified = true;
entry.Property( o => o.<ColumnPropertyToUpdate> ).IsModified = true;
...

ctx.SaveChanges();
```

If you do this, EF will only include the columns you've marked as modified in the UPDATE statement.